# Getting the SessionFactory for a particular Datasource in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So if I want to do a direct SQL query using the session that Grails is using prior to supporting multiple datasources I could do:

def conn = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())

Now the question is that I have multiple datasources and want to grab a connection to a specific one.

How do I do that?

TIA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given a datasource defined in DataSource.groovy as "dataSource_foo", you'll have a `SessionFactory` called `sessionFactory_foo`. So you can dependency-inject it like any other Spring bean:

```
def sessionFactory_foo
```

and use it like this:

```
def conn = new Sql(sessionFactory_foo.currentSession.connection())
```

Comment: That is soo darn simple that I should have just tried it... Thanks Burt... Awesome...

Comment: @Bert You're such a valuable member for grails community, Thanks!

Comment: @burt-beckwith Can you please guide that how can we achieve this in grails 3? I'm using version 3.2.2 but not getting succeeded to connect with multiple datasources and work with them

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the session using a Domain class reference as follows:

```
Book.withSession { session -> 
    def conn = new Sql(session.connection())
    ...
}
```

This method does not require a hardcoded reference to the datasource suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Better declare the data source in your bean (Service, Controller...) to be injected (no need to depend from Hibernate here)

```
def dataSource
```

and use it directly:

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
```

If you have multiple data sources, just follow the naming convention

```
def dataSource_foo
```

Comment: this gobbles up excessive connections better to use sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()