# Grails using SessionFactory vs. dataSource when creating Sql Object

Tags: grails, datasource, sessionfactory

In Grails I could create Sql object in 2 ways:

```
def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
```

I have read this thread here on Stackoverflow: [Getting the SessionFactory for a particular Datasource in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028545/getting-the-sessionfactory-for-a-particular-datasource-in-grails)
... and one of the answers was that dataSource "...*gobbles up excessive connections better to use sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()*"

Is this recommendation correct and what is the difference between those two?

When Inspecting created objects I could see that they are almost the same, just 2 properties were different:
**dataSource** and **useConnection**.

In case of **dataSource** it was *dataSource=TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy and useConnection=null*, while for **sessionFactory** it is *dataSource=null and useConnection=$Proxy 36*.

Why this makes difference with consequence of "gobblin up excessive connections"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment about "gobbling up excessive connections" is based on a few assumptions, which may or may not be true in your case.

The assumption is that Hibernate is going to, or already has, or will, during the request create a connection to the database because of the session in view pattern used by Grails and GORM. In that case you would be using one connection for Hibernate and n-number for your other connections.

If you use a mix of GORM and SQL connections it's safer to get the connection from the sessionFactory.

I seem to recall older versions of Grails use to create the connection even if no GORM methods were executed during the request. I'm not entirely sure that's still the case with more recent versions (2.x+)

Comment: Just an FYI...never store a Sql object in an instance field and reuse.  Create a new Sql instance every time you need to use it.  I can't remember why but I asked Mr. LaForge about this and he said Sql objects could not be reused or shared.

Comment: @ToddWCrone Yes, that is very true. It's because the SQL object implements it's own connection handling for closing the connection and so forth. Not letting it do so is asking for trouble ...